# How to find the right implementation and import for Kotlin API

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am new to Kotlin and struggling with Kotlin code in a Flutter plugin. To use the CustomObjectDetectorOptions API (for example), I must import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.CustomObjectDetectorOptions
and add implementation
'com.google.mlkit:object-detection-custom:17.0.1' to the Gradle file.
I can find a description of the API (in developers.google.com/android/reference) but I don't know a systematic way to figure out the right import and implementation. I have to find example code somewhere. I spend a lot of time on this. Is there a better way? Can Android Studio help me? How will an experienced Kotlin developer do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you are using code which someone else has decided to make available publicly. That code could be published anywhere, and could take any conceivable form. So ultimately, the author of the code ought to tell you somewhere how to find and use their library themselves (and usually does).

Having said that, there are things you can do to fill in the gaps if the author of the code has not made it clear.

##### Finding the library

To find the library, you can look in repositories where libraries are published. The most common are [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central), [Google](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) and, for plugins, the [Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/) (but could be anywhere). Any such repositories you use need to be declared in the `repositories` block of your build file.

In the repositories you can find the "Maven coordinates" for the library, which is the string you pass to `implementation` to tell Gradle which artifact to download, made up of the group, artifact id, and version number. So [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.google.mlkit#com.google.mlkit:object-detection-custom) is your ML Kit library at the Google repo.

Note what `implementation` means is 'place the compiled code from this artifact on the classpath of my JVM program at compile time and runtime'.

##### Using the code

Once you have the library available to your program, then someone at some level has to tell you which class to use to get going<sup>1</sup>.

Imports are often not specified though, but this is not a problem if you are using a modern IDE.

In Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA, once the library is specified in your Gradle build file, make sure the IDE is synced with that build file. As part of the syncing the IDE (if it is working properly!) will index the files of the new library. Then, you can simply type the name of the target class you are trying to use directly into the code and a window should pop up to allow you to choose the correct class, and the IDE will automatically add the correct import statement.

---

<sup>1</sup>You could of course start poking around inside the source code and seeing what's available, which should be possible in your IDE once you've synced your Gradle build. The library code should then appear in the "External Libraries" section of the project in Android Studio.

Comment: A great explanation, thank you very much. Will save me lots of time!